# Why do we use brackets for function parameters?

Tags: mathematics, notation

I know that a function is called "function" because it's an "execution" of operations. Abbreviated notation is f. But why do we write `f(x)` and not `(x)f` or `f_x` or `f-x-` etc. ?

Comment: Besides the ones you list, there is also $x^\sigma$ for function $\sigma$ applied to argument $x$.

Comment: The notation (x)f *has* been used.  For example, Herstein's Topics in Algebra writes functions and operators on the right. At least the edition available 20 years ago did.  I believe algebraists starting in the 1960s promoted this notation, perhaps due to its nice compatibility with drawing functions between sets above an arrow, but it never took off.

Comment: Polish notation dispenses with brackets altogether, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation

Comment: function application is often (usually?) written without parens, e.g f x.  the order, I speculate, is simply due to the left-to-right ordering of latinate writing systems.

Comment: The linear algebra book by H. Rose (https://books.google.de/books?id=mTdAj-Yn4L4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=rose+linear+algebra&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rose%20linear%20algebra&f=false) uses the notation $xf$.

Comment: Nitpick: from a historical perspective it is not correct that $f$ was called a function because it is an execution of operations. Historically closer to the truth is that $f(x)$ was called the function of $x$, because it depends on $x$, or it is determined by $x$. The idea of calling $f$ the function came roughly 200 years later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) :

- **E045** : [Additamentum ad dissertationem de infinitis curvis eiusdem generis (Addendum to the dissertation on infinite(ly many) curves of the same type)](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/), originally published in *Commentarii academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae*; 7, 1740, pp.184-200:

> si $f(\frac x a + c)$ denotet functionem quamcunque ipsius $\frac x a + c$

---

The definition of *function* was already present into:

- [Johann Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Bernoulli), *Remarques sur ce qu'on a donne jusqu'ici de solutions des problemes sur les isopdrimitres*, published in *Mem.Acad.roy.sci*, Paris, 1718. See [Opera omnia, Tomus II](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ku_1PxvPHPEC&pg=PA241), page 241:

> *Definition*. On appelle ici *Fonction* d'une grandeur variable, une quantité
>   composée de quelque maniére que ce soit de cette grandeur variable et de constantes.

In the same [mémoire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9moire) [[page 243](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ku_1PxvPHPEC&pg=PA243)] Bernoulli proposed the Greek letter $\phi$ as a notation for the *caractéristique* of a function, writing the argument without brackets: $\phi Pb$.

I presume that the improved symbolism due to Euler was devised in order to avoid the mistake of interpreting justaxposition as multiplication.

Comment: If this was Eulers first use of the function notation, it's tempting to speculate that the tradition of carrying along brackets around the argument originated from this example, where brackets were _necessary_. (I'm assuming brackets were already used at that time to denote precedence of operations, as in $3(2+5)$?)

Comment: @MichaelBächtold - brackets in expression was used; see e.g. Benoulli's text linked.