# Did Euler ever write $f(x)$, with parentheses?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, notation, euler

Euler is often credited with introducing the notation $f(x)$, and people  [cite](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5204/3462) the example $f(\frac{x}{a}+c)$, where he *had* to use parentheses around the function argument. On the other hand, when the argument was a single letter like $x$, I have mainly seen Johann Bernoulli and Euler just write $f\, x$ or $f\colon x$ (or $\phi\, x$), *without* the parentheses. If I recall correctly even Lagrange in his lectures introduced the function notation without parentheses.

**Question:** Did Euler (or Johann Bernoulli) ever write $f(x)$?

In case the answer is no, the follow up question is: when did it become standard to put parentheses around $x$?

Comment: Many papers of Euler can be found in the arxiv.

Comment: Already answered in the post: [why-do-we-use-brackets-for-function-parameters](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5202/why-do-we-use-brackets-for-function-parameters)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it's not really answered there, even though that question is related.

Comment: See document E045, page 186.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see him write $f(\frac{x}{a}+c)$ there. Maybe I'm overlooking something. Certainly he cannot leave the parenthesis out in that case.

Comment: For Lagrange, see [Théorie (1847)](https://books.google.it/books?id=15IKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA7), page 7: he writes $fx$ and $f(x^2), f(x,y)$. Thus, my conjecture is simply this: the Bernoulli's $\phi x$ and Euler's $fx$ notations evolved gradually to use parentheses only to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m guessing **no**. But how does one make sure? (Maybe with [85+](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/history+of+science?SGWID=0-40295-6-121672-0) volumes of clean pdfs...)

Cajori, who started that $f(\frac xa+c)$ example, [points out](https://archive.org/stream/AHistoryOfMathematicalNotationVolII#page/n292) a $\varphi(z)$ in **D’Alembert** ([1754, p. 50](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bw8OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA50)).

For “standard”, I would say **Lacroix** ([1797, p. 87](https://archive.org/stream/traitducalculdi02lacrgoog#page/n128)):

> 4. Pour représenter une fonction sans indiquer, en aucune manière comment elle peut être composée, je me servirai de la caractéristique
>   $\mathrm f$; et il faudra entendre, par l'expression $\mathrm f(x)$, une fonction
>   quelconque de $x$, en comprenant sous cette dénomination tout ce  que
>   comporte la définition du mot *fonction* (*Intr.* nº 1) : on  doit donc
>   bien se garder de prendre la lettre $\mathrm f$ pour un coefficient de $x$.
>   J’indiquerai la substitution de $x+k$ aulieu de $x$ dans $\mathrm f(x)$,  en
>   écrivant $\mathrm f(x+k)$, et cela voudra dire que le résultat est composé en
>   $x+k$, comme la fonction primitive l’est en $x$.

Side remark tying into your [other question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/who-first-considered-the-f-in-fx-as-an-object-in-itself-and-who-decided-t): This book of Lacroix writes “the function $f$” very often; e.g. pp. 93, 212, 258, 483–496, 502, mainly when describing results of Monge who also did this a lot (but avoided unnecessary parentheses). I think “$f$” all started with solutions of PDEs depending on “arbitrary functions” — though only Dedekind, I would say, made them “objects” in the sense you want at the other question.

---

**Edit:**
In E213 “Remarques sur les mémoires précedens de M. Bernoulli” (1755), just quoted [elsewhere](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6206/is-the-prime-notation-for-derivatives-f-due-to-euler), you can see Euler “forget” his evaluation colon and slip into writing $\Phi'(x)$ (p. 215) and eventually $\Phi(x)$ ([p. 216](https://archive.org/stream/berlin-histoire-1753-pub1755#page/n218)). Same thing in E441 (1773, [p. 429](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=hvd.32044092611839&num=429)). So in the end, **yes**.

Comment: It's interesting that several pages before introducing the function notation $f(x)$, Lacroix uses extensively the notation $\mathrm{l}\, x$ to denote the logarithm of $x$, _without parenthesis_, and without worrying that one may confuse the letter l for a coefficient. It also raises the question if any of his contemporaries ever called l a "caractéristique d'une fonction".

Comment: @MichaelBächtold Yes, [Cauchy](https://archive.org/stream/coursdanalysedel00cauc#page/309/mode/1up) [for](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_BmOo00FGCuAC#page/n68/mode/1up) [sure](https://archive.org/stream/exercicesdanalys04caucuoft#page/324/mode/1up).

Answer (score 2):

You can find all of Euler's original papers in the [Euler archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/index.html). Glancing through his later papers does not yield a hit. But if you are interested enough you can probably exclude that notation for all his writings.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what you mean by me excluding that notation for all his writings.

Comment: I meant that you can look into all of his papers in the Euler archieve and probably you will find that Euler did never use f(x). But I am not sure and too lazy to do so myself.

Comment: No problem. I was just hoping that maybe someone has already seen him write f(x). I'm also to lazy to search all his writings. I'll leave this open a few more days.