# When and why did $\frac{dy}{dx}$ become $\frac{d}{dx}y$?

Tags: notation, calculus

It's obvious for us, that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can also be written as $\frac{d}{dx}y$, but skimming through Leibniz or Eulers writings I couldn't see them write the latter. I speculate that this change happened out of laziness, when the expression for $y$ became very long, but I wonder if it was also related with a shift of perspective from treating $d$ as the main operator (Leibniz and Euler) to treating $d/dx$ as main one (maybe starting with Lagrange?).

(If this question seems to be about a triviality, consider writing $\frac{\log}{\log 2}x$ or $(\log/\log 2) x$ instead of $\frac{\log x}{\log 2}$ in an article or in front of students.)

Comment: @Namaste Sure, but what you write is not specific to $d/dx$. It applies in general to operators. Should we write $\cos \phi$ or $\cos (\phi)$? $dx$ or $d(x)$? Historically it was without parenthesis, unless the parenthesis were necessary for disambiguation, as in $\cos xy$ or $dxy$. Even $f(x)$ was [originally written without parenthesis](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/did-euler-ever-write-fx-with-parentheses).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean conceptually, I remember reading that Arbogast “[was the first writer to separate the symbols of operation from those of quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Fran%C3%A7ois_Antoine_Arbogast).” Among those he influenced were [Babbage, Herschel, Peacock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Society), in whose edited translation of Lacroix that phrase is used to justify writing Taylor’s formula for $u=f(x)$ in the form
$$
\Delta u =\bigl(e^{h\frac d{dx}}-1\bigr)u
\tag{*}
$$

([1816](https://archive.org/details/anelementarytre00babbgoog/page/n497), see pp. 486–489) — an improvement over the rather clumsy $\Delta u =e^{\frac{du}{dx}h}-1$ of Lagrange ([1774](https://archive.org/details/nouv-berlin-1772/page/n267), p. 195), Lacroix ([1800](https://archive.org/details/traitducalculdi00lacrgoog/page/n28), p. 13), Brinkley ([1807](//doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1807.0007)), or Laplace ([1820](https://archive.org/details/theorieanaldepro00laplrich/page/n230), p. 41). (Arbogast wrote it $\Delta u=(e^{h\partial.}-1)\times u$ ([1800](https://archive.org/details/ducalculdesdri00arbouoft/page/350), p. 350), and Lacroix adopted (*) in his second edition ([1819](https://archive.org/details/traitducalculdi04lacrgoog/page/n89), p. 61).) The ability to meaningfully write such formulas may well be the “why” you are after.

If you mean just typographically, I don’t know if earlier examples exist!

**Edit:** As noted today on [MO](//mathoverflow.net/questions/352294/earliest-reference-on-the-calculation-of-derivatives-by-fourier-transform), Fourier (maybe first?) uses a “bare” $\smash{\frac d{dx}}$ in *Théorie analytique de la chaleur* ([1822](//archive.org/details/thorieanalytiq00four/page/540), Art. 399-405, 410-414, 419-422,...).

Comment: Yes, I just meant typographically in the particular case $dy/dx$ vs. $d/dx\; y$. But your answer is good since it's more general and gives me pointers to search for the particular case.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold Oh right — Babbage et al. (pp. 486, 492) never seem to apply a “bare” $d\,/\,dx$. But their student De Morgan does ([1836](https://books.google.com/books?id=GoM_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA83), pp. 52, 53, 83); earlier, Hamilton ([1831](https://archive.org/details/transactionsofro016oya/page/n512), pp. 102, 104, 106; [1834](https://doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1834.0017), p. 261):$$\frac d{dt}\frac{δ\mathrm T}{δ\eta'}-\frac{δ\mathrm T}{δ\eta}=\frac{δ\mathrm U}{δ\eta}.$$